# Suppress Page Header when there are no details

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

This is the code i am using now to Suppress the page header.

1)

```
Shared numbervar rownum := 0;
rownum
```

Used a shared variable to calculate rows in a page and placed this in page footer to reset on every page

2)

```
Shared numbervar rownum;
rownum := rownum + 1
```

calculating rows and placed this in the details section.

Both these fields are suppress in the report so that the user cannot see them.

Now in the Page header i have placed the below formula

```
if Shared Numbervar rownum < 1
then true
Else
False
```

This works like a charm...but if there are no records in the second page it show a blank page.Details section keep Together checkbox is enabled.

Let me know how  to avoid this.

----------Solution for Blank page ------------
Report Footer doesnt contain any data and I didnt suppress it.Show the blank page was displayed.Now that I suppress it its working fine.

here ends the search for solving the page header suppression when not using Groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, this doesn't make much sense. You want to suppress the Page Header when there are no records in the detail section?

Comment: Yes,but for me its not as simple as that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution

This is the code i am using now to Suppress the page header.

1)

```
Shared numbervar rownum := 0;
rownum
```

Used a shared variable to calculate rows in a page and placed this in page footer to reset on every page

2)

```
Shared numbervar rownum;
rownum := rownum + 1
```

calculating rows and placed this in the details section.

Both these fields are suppress in the report so that the user cannot see them.

Now in the Page header i have placed the below formula

```
if Shared Numbervar rownum < 1
then true
Else
False
```

Suppress any blank footers if not used to avoid blank pages.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise to use a Group instead of putting the data in the Page Header. That will make your life a lot easier. If that is not an option, create a Running Total. As the field to summarize use one of the fields in the Detail Section (Paracetamol, Crocin). Do a count as the type of Summary. Under Evaluate choose "For each Record". under Reset, choose "On change of Field" and choose a field from your Header Section (Item Description). Now put that running total in your detail section. Check the values and make sure that it numbers each record correctly and resets if there is a new item in the Page Header. Now do a suppress statement in the Page Header that goes like `RTotal0 < 1`. That should suppress your Page Header if there are no records in the detail section.

Comment: i think this will work only when the ItemDescription is different.In my case ItemDescription is not different(always)>We can have a product from different vendors.So this is not working.

Comment: I have edited the question.Can you help me with avoiding blank page